# how to make the img at the left side and the texts at the right side vertically line up

Tags: html, css

**css**

```
.container{
   height: 250px;
   padding 10px 0;
}
.col-left{
   display: inline-block;
   background-image:url("support.png");
   height:235px; 
   width:300px;
}

.col-right{
   display: inline-block;
   width:600px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-left"></div>
    <div class="col-right">
       <h1>this is my title</h1>
       <p>to reach their Potential</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

I want the img at the left and the texts at the right

1. to show on the same line.
2. vertically line up(texts appear in the middle position of img)
   how could I do this?

Comment: Can you please give us link to `jsfiddle.net`. it will help us to understand your problem, clearly !!!

Comment: Have you tried using [float](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position) ?

Comment: Fixing the numerous typos and syntax errors in your CSS would be a good start...

Comment: You can add the table with two column also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VhKQ4/)

```
.container {
    height: 250px;
    padding 10px 0;
}
.col-left {
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url("http://www.lois-systems.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/support.png");
    height:235px;
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.col-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width:600px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.col-right h1, .col-right p {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: it seems work, but why you put this line .col-right{vertical-align:middle;} and margin:0;?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question I found that `Float` will solve your problem. Float works same as `inline-block`. You can learn more about this from this url http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/

So, as far as my knowledge concert I will go for following solution, Hope this will help you.

CSS :

```
.container {width:100%;height: 250px;padding 10px 0;}
.col-left {float:left;background-image:url("support.png");height:235px; width:30%;}
.co-right {float:left;width:70%}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ugQCU/

Comment: now they show on the same line, but the texts line up with the top of img, how could i make texts line up with the mid of img?

Comment: @user2243528 : You might need to updated CSS Padding as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you want to achieve try this i've just added a div for displaying vertical align use this and let me know 
**Html code is**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-left"></div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <div class="col-right-wrap">
            <h1>this is my title</h1>
            <p>to reach their Potential</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**and css**

```
.container{
    height: 250px;
    padding 10px 0;
}
.col-left { 
    float:left; /*give a direction where you want */
    display: inline-block;
    background-image:url("images/support.png");
    height:235px; 
    width:300px; 
}
.col-right {
    float:left; /*give a direction where you want */
    display: inline-block;
    width:600px;
}
/* align however you want adjust this below code according to you */
.col-right-wrap{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: display:table-cell; 
vertical-align:middle; does not work the way it should be, the texts does not show at the middle of img

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code the same and CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 235px;
    padding 10px 0;
}
.col-left {
    position: absolute;
    background: #AAA;
    height:235px;
    width:300px;
}
.col-right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 235px;
    padding-left: 310px;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/zWNCP/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should be what you want:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x235" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
         <h1>this is my title</h1>

        <p>to reach their Potential</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
    padding 10px 0;
}
.col-left {
    float:left;
    background-image:url("support.png");
    height:235px;
    width:300px;
}
.col-right {
    float:left;
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ugQCU/2/)

Do note that for the placement of the text I used padding, which may not be an ideal solution.